# How does "Angular 2.0 for TypeScript" (alpha) animation work?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am very new in the Angular scene. I just started to learn Angular 2.0 for TypeScript and I was wondering, how the animation (like in a simple HTML with jQuery) works in Angular 2.0

In the homepage of the Angular 2.0 (angular.io > Features) you can see, that there is a way to do animation in "Angular 2.0 for TypeScript".

In my research I found something like this:
http://www.angular-dev.com/angular-connect-slides/#/26/0/

But I think this is just a normal JavaScript code. And I am not sure if 
ngAnimate 2.0 is that, what I am looking for.

Unfortunately, I can't find anymore information about that.

**What I want to do, is very simple:**

When I click just in a simple div container, I want that another div-container appears (which is in the beginning unvisible).

In jQuery, it would be something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_toggle

But what I want, is this animation in TypeScript.
Do you have any idea how I reach this goal?

Thanks for your answers in advance!

**EDIT**
I am sorry, I forgot to mention, what exactly I want.
I want to use toggle, but something like in Windows 10:

When you press "Windows + A", it will appear a sidebar on the right side.
Exactly that is what I want with animation on the website, when you click on a div-container, and not just simple appearing and disappearing.

I think the jQuery code would be something like that (only for appearing with a time delay)

```
$("divA").click(function() {
    $("divB").toggle(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use CSS, or [AnimationBuilder](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/animate/animation_builder.ts)

For the CSS way you can check this [example](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/playground/src/animate) from their repo that does exactly what you are looking for.

With `AnimationBuilder` you can simulate the same behavior like this

First you set up the template that'll hold the button and div to toggle

```js
@Component({
  // Setting up some styles
  template: `
    <div animate-box #box="ab"  style="height:0; width:50%; overflow: hidden;">Some content</div>
    <button (click)="box.toggle(visible = !visible)">Animate</button>
  `,
  directives : [AnimateBox] // See class below
})
```

Then you create the directive that will handle the animation

```js
@Directive({
  selector : '[animate-box]',
  exportAs : 'ab' // Necessary, we export it and we can get its 'toggle' method in the template
})
class AnimateBox {
  constructor(private _ab: AnimationBuilder, private _e: ElementRef) {}

  toggle(isVisible: boolean = false) {
    let animation = this._ab.css();
    animation
      .setDuration(1000); // Duration in ms

    // If is not visible, we make it slide down
    if(!isVisible) {

      animation
        // Set initial styles
        .setFromStyles({height: '0', width: '50%', overflow: 'hidden'})
        // Set styles that will be added when the animation ends
        .setToStyles({height: '300px'})
    } 
    // If is visible we make it slide up
    else {
      animation
        .setFromStyles({height: '300px', width: '50%'})
        .setToStyles({height: '0'})
    }

    // We start the animation in the element, in this case the div
    animation.start(this._e.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Animation API](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular2/src/animate), it's super simple, really, really simple.

**Notes**

This is a temporary API, the new one called ngAnimate 2.0 is not yet available. But you can check what's new in @matsko's talk at [AngularConnect - ngAnimate 2.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izp5N2eeogg).

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xkHA4HWwT9McoA4sbUnI?p=preview) with a repro.

I hope it helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! I really could use it.

But can you please help me one more time with this?
Your solution is **perfect**, but I also have to use it in another way:
My situation is that I have **app2.ts** which sets many divs. When I click on one of these divs, then the only **one** same "animation-div" should appear. But this "animation-div" is in **app.ts**. I think a good solution is just to use EventEmitter (like a state) that I am using.
My question is:
When the subscribe function from EventEmitter is called, how can I call the toggle function from the certain #box in app.ts?

Comment: I just made another decision. I am using right now the css solution. This might be easier. The AnimationBuilder is still a good way to solve this problem.

Comment: Don't understand the `toggle` function. Shouldn't it be the contrary: `// If is visible, we make it slide up
    if(isVisible) {
      animation
        // Set initial styles
        .setFromStyles({height: '0', width: '50%', overflow: 'hidden'})
        // Set styles that will be added when the animation ends
        .setToStyles({height: '300px'})` ?

Comment: Important!!: `import { AnimationBuilder } from 'angular2/src/animate/animation_builder';`, don't import it from `angular2/animate`as it won't work.

Comment: Has any code for ngAnimate 2 been published yet? The API shown in @matsko's talk looks pretty cool, but I haven't been able to find where the implementation work is happening. Maybe I haven't been looking in the right places?

Comment: @eppsilon there's just this PR introducing ngAnimate, but it's work in progress https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7698

Comment: broken link first link.

Answer (score 3):

For your simple "animation" you only need ng-if:

```
<div (click)="showDiv2 = !showDiv2">toggle</div>
<div *ng-if="showDiv2">div 2</div>
```

<strike>BTW, Angular 2 animation is not available yet.</strike> The animations documentation [has landed](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html).

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention, what exactly I want.
I want to use toggle, but something like in Windows 10:

When you press "Windows + A", it will appear a sidebar on the right side.
Exactly that is what I want with animation on the website, when you click on a div-container, and not just simple appearing and disappearing.

I think the jQuery code would be something like that (only for appearing with a time delay)

    $("divA").click(function() {
        $("divB").toggle(1000);
    });


So, do you think is there a way in Angular 2.0 to reach this "sidebar animation"?

Comment: @SyleKu, welcome to StackOverflow.  As you can see, it is very important to be specific about what exactly you need help with.  I'm not aware of any  way to do what you want with the current version of Angular 2.  You would have to do something like `(click)="animateDiv2(div2, 1000)"` and then write function animateDiv2() to do what toggle() does -- which I assume means modify CSS property values over the time duration specified.