# Angular2 Animation on a Component

Tags: angular

I am trying to apply a Slide Down/Up animation to a component, I have also seen the below post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34170712/2755616

This solution seems to work on a DIV, but in my case I have a component in a page which is shown only if certain condition is met. When that condition is true, I want the component to slide down, and when it become false again, I want it to slideup and become invisible.

Toggle Component

But this doesn't seem to work, when following guidelines provided in above stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the directive in the answer you mentioned to make it take an input of type boolean and on change of the input you display/hide the element/component. [plunker with example](http://plnkr.co/edit/lglhzHpnUuIjnJNuNOJ0?p=preview)

```
@Directive({
  selector : '[animate-box]',
})
export class AnimateBox {
  constructor(private _ab: AnimationBuilder, private _e: ElementRef) {}

  @Input('animate-box')
  set animateBox(isVisible: boolean) {
    let animation = this._ab.css();
    // if isVisible is true, animate show. if it's false animate hide
  ...
  }
}
```

And in your component:

```
<some-component [animate-box]="isVisible"></some-component>
```

One thing to keep in mind is that in order for the animation *in the plunker* to work, Your element/component should have a display of type `block`. That's why it wasn't working for you in the first place, because components has `display:inline` by default.

Comment: Thank you Abdul Rahman that was helpful, now two more questions:

1. When I replace height in AnimateBox component with 100% (instead of 100px), the slide effect doesn't work at all. As the height of the sliding component is unknown I want to use 100% instead of setting it to fixed number of pixels.

2. I have to conditionally include component in my page so I use *ngIf, but when I apply this slide effect on that component it doesn't work, apparently because the component doesn't exist in DOM, any pointers on that?

Comment: Actually I have a page with different sections and each section has a Add Record link, when Add Record link is clicked I want the corresponding form (which is a component) to slideIn.

Comment: @NaveedAhmed I have made some edits on `ngIf` directive and created a new animated version. [check this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GxDQMWuUN4xZCbcraf66?p=preview). I will try to explain it in my answer if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be near to what I need but I want the component to be hidden by default so for this when I set isVisible = false; in AppComponent it generates "error angular2.dev.js:23941 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'rootNodes' of undefined in [isVisible in AppComponent@2:19]"

Comment: @NaveedAhmed I updated the plunker, please check it again

Comment: @NaveedAhmed you are very welcome, I will try to improve the directive and put it in my answer soon :)

Comment: That would be great (y)